# Access SQLite DB in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, sqflite

I am creating a DB in my native Android code using SQLite. Now I want to access the same DB in Flutter, below is my code:

```dart
class DatabaseHelper
{
    static final _dbName="abc.db";
    static final _dbVersion=1;
    DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
    static final DatabaseHelper instance=DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
    static Database _database;
    Future<Database> get datatbase async
    {
        if(_database!=null) {
            print(_database.path);
            return _database;
        }/* */
    }


    Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> getAllLogs()async
    {
        final Database db= await instance.datatbase;
        return await db.query("calls_history");
    }
```

Whenever I call `getAllLogs` in my Flutter `Widget` I get the error: `calls_history doesn't exist`.

However, when I run the same query on native, it returns me the result

Answer (score 4):

On flutter side you can use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) plugin, this plugin is built on top of native SQLite so you don't need to do anything special just refer to the same database name in flutter.

In one of my flutter projects I have used native android to code to receive messages and save them in SQLite database and on the flutter side I have used same database using sqflite to display the contents of database.
Here is the flutter side code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class SMSHelper {
  Database? db;

  Future open() async {
    db = await openDatabase(
        //  by default path for database on the device is /data/data/<your app id>/databases/<your database file.db>
        join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'ofs_sms_database.db'),
        version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE smslogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, employeeID TEXT, department TEXT, module TEXT, message TEXT, safeUnsafeStatus TEXT, contactNo Text, dateTime INTEGER)");
    });
  }

  Future<void> insertSMS(SMSLog smsLog) async {
    await db?.insert(
      'smslogs',
      smsLog.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  Future<List<SMSLog>> getAllSMS() async {
    if (db == null) {
      open();
    }
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? maps = await db?.query('smslogs');

    // Convert the List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List<Dog>.
    if (maps != null) {
      return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
        return SMSLog(
            employeeID: maps[i]['employeeID'],
            department: maps[i]['department'],
            module: maps[i]['module'],
            message: maps[i]['message'],
            safeUnsafeStatus: maps[i]['safeUnsafeStatus'],
            contactNo: maps[i]['contactNo'],
            dateTime: maps[i]['dateTime']);
      });
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  Future close() async => db?.close();
}

class SMSLog {
  final String employeeID;
  final String department;
  final String module;
  final String message;
  final String safeUnsafeStatus;
  final String contactNo;
  final int dateTime;

  SMSLog(
      {required this.employeeID,
      required this.department,
      required this.module,
      required this.message,
      required this.safeUnsafeStatus,
      required this.contactNo,
      required this.dateTime});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'employeeID': employeeID,
      'department': department,
      'module': module,
      'message': message,
      'safeUnsafeStatus': safeUnsafeStatus,
      'contactNo': contactNo,
      'dateTime': dateTime
    };
  }
}
```